# How to execute function over each element in RDD and join outputs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm very new to Spark and I am using Spark 1.6.0.

I have an RDD which is: `RDD[Array[Array[String], Long]]`

I would like to run each element in the RDD through a function which takes `Array[Array[String], Long]` as input and returns a `ListBuffer[Array[Int]]` as output.

The computations of each element in the RDD can be done in parallel, they are not dependent on each other. However, once all of the elements of the RDD have been run through the function I would like to join all of the `ListBuffer[Array[Int]]` outputs together, into one single `ListBuffer[Array[Int]]` (order here is not relevant either, but they should all be in the same datastructure).

What would be the best way to do so? I could foreach the RDD and run them through the function, however then I'm not sure how to handle the output and thereafter perform this merge at the driver.

This seems to be possible with Accumulators. The function as mentioned earlier is not just a single line of code, it is something like 20+ lines. So if we have this function:

```
def func(data: Array[Array[String], Long]): ListBuffer[Array[Int]] {
    // create ListBuffer
    // iterate over data
        // do some operations on an element in data
        // add some entry to the ListBuffer
    // add the ListBuffer to the Accumulator or return ListBuffer?
}
```

How could I wrap this all up together? Can I do something like:

```
// create Accumulator
// RDD.foreach() // call the func and pass Accumulator as argument?
```

Or:

```
val accum = // a ListBuffer[Array[Int]] accumulator
RDD.foreach(x => accum.add(func(x)))
```

Comment: Can you add sample input and expected output? Also, what is the size of your RDD? Can it be collected on to the driver safely? Did you try using Accumulators ?

Comment: Unfornately I am not allowed to give too much details. The input is essentially a csv row and the Long is an index attached to it. The output is a matrix of indexes. The size of RDD is quite big, and one RDD can be stored on the driver safely, however there will be multiple programs of this running in parallel (since Spark will listen to an input source). I'm gonna look up Accumulators now.

Comment: Accumulators seem like they can solve the issue of calculating parts of the output seperately and adding the output to the accumulator.

Comment: See my edit, I added some things that might make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use `map` followed by `collect` if you need the results on the driver.

[map](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@map[U](f:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$3:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]) applies a function to every element in an RDD.

> **map[U](f: (T) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[U]** Return a new RDD by applying a function to all elements of this RDD.

In your case, `T` is `Array[Array[String], Long]` with `U` being `ListBuffer[Array[Int]]`. If you have a function `f` that does the transformation of elements of type `T`, `map` is your friend.

Comment: @osk Pleasure's mine. If that's what worked for you, could you please accept it as the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I was about to do that, was just testing it out. Starting to get the hang of Spark now it feels like.